# Send different express server based on the request

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, angular-universal

I built an angular application and all was good but one of the requirements was, depending on the page you were on, the meta tags needed to be changed which is why I added angular universal to the project. Adding angular universal fixed the issue of the meta tags requirement. However, this addition is causing a lot of errors that I don't think are possible to solve or will take a lot of time to solve.

Some of the problems were:

1. Some libraries don't render as supposed to (ngx-owl-carousel-o, ng-bootstrap, iconify and many more). [Link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923727/ngx-owl-carousel-o-and-iconify-not-rendering-correctly-with-angular-universal)
2. I am using a third party library ([@coreui/angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coreui/angular)) and it causing a lot of errors with SSR.
3. The stylesheet is not working as expected to.
4. Some components don't render or don't render as expected to.
5. **(The most important)** Some things like (localStorage, window, location, document) that cannot be rendered on server side and only on client side requires you to add the isPlatformBrowser flag to check the whether or not the app was called from the server or the client side. However, when I add this flag the items these items don't render either way

Is there a way in the server.ts file to detect whether the request is coming from a browser or not. Or even detect if the request is coming from Google SEO, Twitter, Whatsapp or Facebook.

Something like:

```
if(isBrowser){
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });
}
else{
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });
}
```

This way if the request is coming from an SEO the meta tags will be updated correctly and if the request is coming from a user(browser) they see what they expect to.

Comment: "Is there a way in the server.ts file to detect whether the request is coming from a browser or not. Or even detect if the request is coming from Google SEO, Twitter, Whatsapp or Facebook." — **Don't**. Serving different content to browsers and search engines is just going to get you SEO penalities … and serving the correct meta tags to search engines with the wrong content is also going to get you SEO penalities. Fix [your real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) instead of processing this negative workaround.

Comment: What angular version are you using? For angular 12 and lower you can use `extractCss`

Comment: I’m using Angular 14